# XML How to count based on subgroups

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following data:

```
<countries>
    <continent name="Europe">
        <country>France</country>
        <country>United Kingdom</country>
        ...
    </continent>
    <continent name="North America">
        <country>Canada</country>
        <country>United States</country>
        ...
    </continent>
</countries>

<clients>
    <client>
        <name>John</name>
        <country>Canada</country>
    </client>
    ...
</clients>
```

I can count the number of clients per country with something like the following:

```
<xsl:key name="clientcountry" match="client" use="country"/>

<xsl:for-each select="countries//country">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ': ', count(key('clientcountry', .)))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I count the number of clients per continent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:for-each select="countries/continent">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ': ', count(key('clientcountry', country)))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Wait how does that work? Does `country` refer to all underlying country elements? So it's possible to input multiple nodes at once with `key()`?

Comment: Sure, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key: "When the second argument to the key function is of type node-set, then the result is the union of the result of applying the key function to the string value of each of the nodes in the argument node-set".